# Why my JavaScript draggable slider is not working?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a draggable slider with JavaScript. But it is not working on my one. I have tried the same JS code on a built-in HTML, from W3 School and that worked fluently. I can't understand what's the problem with my code!
I've tried almost everything on my concern. But still facing the same problem

```js
let lists = document.querySelector("#lists");
let cursorRunningPosition;
let cursorStartingPosition;
let cursorMoved;
let scrollLeft;
let isdown = false;

lists.addEventListener("mousedown", (e) => {
    isdown = true;
    cursorStartingPosition = e.pageX;
    lists.style.cursor = "grabbing";
    if (isdown === true) {
        scrollLeft = lists.scrollLeft;
    }
})
lists.addEventListener("mouseup", (f) => {
    isdown = false;
    lists.style.cursor = "auto";
})
lists.addEventListener("mouseleave", (f) => {
    isdown = false;
    lists.style.cursor = "auto";
})
lists.addEventListener("mousemove", (g) => {
    g.preventDefault();
    if (isdown === true) {
        cursorRunningPosition = g.pageX;
        cursorMoved = cursorRunningPosition - cursorStartingPosition;
        lists.scrollLeft = scrollLeft - cursorMoved;
    }
})
```

```css
li{
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color: lightcoral;
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
}
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#lists {
    display: flex;
    width: 157%;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.container {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 37vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-left: 20%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Test file</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="lists">
            <li class="li-list">Home</li>
            <li class="li-list">About</li>
            <li class="li-list">Contact</li>
            <li class="li-list">Portfolio</li>
            <li class="li-list">Testimonials</li>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please try to find out what the exact error is so someone can help you out. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const lists = document.querySelector(".container");
let cursorRunningPosition;
let cursorStartingPosition;
let cursorMoved;
let scrollLeft;
let isdown = false;


lists.addEventListener("mousedown", (e) => {
    isdown = true;
    cursorStartingPosition = e.pageX;
    lists.style.cursor = "grabbing";
    if (isdown === true) {
        scrollLeft = lists.scrollLeft;
    }
})
lists.addEventListener("mouseup", (f) => {
    isdown = false;
    lists.style.cursor = "auto";
})
lists.addEventListener("mouseleave", (f) => {
    isdown = false;
    lists.style.cursor = "auto";
})
lists.addEventListener("mousemove", (g) => {
    g.preventDefault();
    if (isdown == true) {
        cursorRunningPosition = g.pageX;
        cursorMoved = cursorRunningPosition - cursorStartingPosition;
        lists.scrollLeft = scrollLeft - cursorMoved;
    }
})
```

```css
li{
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color: lightcoral;
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
}
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#lists {
    display: flex;
    width: 157%;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.container {
    width: 80%;
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 37vh;
    margin-left: 20%;
    overflow: auto;
}
.container::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

/* Hide scrollbar for IE, Edge and Firefox */
.container {
  -ms-overflow-style: none;  /* IE and Edge */
  scrollbar-width: none;  /* Firefox */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Test file</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="lists">
            <li class="li-list">Home</li>
            <li class="li-list">About</li>
            <li class="li-list">Contact</li>
            <li class="li-list">Portfolio</li>
            <li class="li-list">Testimonials</li>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I played around with this and `const` worked better then `var` or `let` and the css for the container:

```
.container {
    width: 80%;
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 37vh;
    margin-left: 20%;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

width to 80% and margin-left to 20% and 'overflow: auto' that enables scrolling. then remove scroll bar:

```
.container::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

/* Hide scrollbar for IE, Edge and Firefox */
.container {
  -ms-overflow-style: none;  /* IE and Edge */
  scrollbar-width: none;  /* Firefox */
}
```

**PS:** Click the 'Expand snippet' to see it better!